# asp.net dropdownlist ajax call without ajaxtoolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have searched on SO and search engines, but can't find a solution.
Is it possible to make an ajax call for an asp.net dropdownlist without using an ajaxtoolkit or jquery?
If so, how would I make an ajax call for a dropdownlist box (selecting a value from one dropdown, populates the next dropdownlist control).

Comment: can you use JavaScript or not?

Comment: yes, traditional javascript is good

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use Dojo for one.  What is your problem with using ajaxtoolkit or jquery?

Comment: End client will not allow downloading jquery library or ajaxtoolkit onto their environment.

Comment: Then I guess you will have to code it raw, there is a guide here http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<asp:DropDownList>` set `autopostback="true"`

then in page_load:

```
if (page.isPostback) 
{
   if (Request.Form("__EVENTTARGET") == DROPDOWNID.UniqueID)
   {
        //POPULATE OTHER DROPDOWN
   }
}
```

Where DROPDOWNID is the id you gave your asp:dropdownlist

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is a postback rather than Ajax I think.

Comment: but he wanted to achieve this: selecting a value from one dropdown, populates the next dropdownlist control
Combining this with an Update Panel and no one notices a postback is happening

Comment: Yes, you made no mention of the UpdatePanel, but this will effectively do Ajax for you.  Note, though, that it will require you to use a ScriptManager, which will behind the scenes download the MS Ajax client script libraries.

Comment: yeah i didn't mention it because i think MJH just wanted to achieve the populatin of the dropdown after a selection in the first dropdown. i am not sure if he really needs ajax.